# Google Play Games and Profile Pictures

Tags: android, google-play-games

Recently, Google Play Games updated their service to work without Google+ account, and instead, players create their own nickname, and choose a profile picture.

How exactly can I load this profile picture to display it?

Before, I used `getIconImageUri()` of `Player`-class to display the Google+ profile image, but nowadays it just throws some strange exception.

Here's a snip of the exception:

```
03-04 17:04:57.399 5076-5543/? W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.games.chimera.GamesContentProviderProxy from ProcessRecord{42f038e8 9143:com.mygame.test/u0a132} (pid=9143, uid=10132) that is not exported from uid 10013
03-04 17:04:57.425 9143-9164/? W/ImageView: Unable to open content: content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/85348a8/343
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.games.chimera.GamesContentProviderProxy from ProcessRecord{42f038e8 9143:com.mygame.test/u0a132} (pid=9143, uid=10132) that is not exported from uid 10013
                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
```

Comment: Can you provide the logs for the exception thrown?

Comment: @adjuremods There you go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the [ImageManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager) now since the images are stored locally on the device.

```
public void showPlayerImage(int imgViewId) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(imgViewId);

    Player me = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);

    ImageManager mgr = ImageManager.create(this);
    mgr.loadImage(image, me.getIconImageUri());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm.

Comment: its working, but next time am open the app it will not show.