# Retrieve user's Google Play Game service profile data

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to get the user's profile picture to put in layout of my game, is there a way to do it?

I tryied this but never been triggered!

```
public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.IDImage));
    LeaderboardScore lbs = result.getScore();
    int score = (int) lbs.getRawScore();
    String name = lbs.getScoreHolderDisplayName();
    Uri urlimage = lbs.getScoreHolderHiResImageUri();
    Uri urlicon = lbs.getScoreHolderIconImageUri();
    ImageManager manager = ImageManager.create(this);
    manager.loadImage(image, urlicon);
}
```

Can i get some help please!!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods belong to the [Player class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Player#getIconImageUri()) and the way that others have done it is place the calls inside a function and call that function.

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784346/google-play-games-and-profile-pictures):

```
public void showPlayerImage(int imgViewId) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(imgViewId);

    Player me = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);

    ImageManager mgr = ImageManager.create(this);
    mgr.loadImage(image, me.getIconImageUri());
}
```