# Google play games user profile image not loading

Tags: android, image, google-play-services, google-play-games, loading-image

Apologies for reposting the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784346/google-play-games-and-profile-pictures) but I get an error using this method and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
  mPlayersClient = Games.getPlayersClient(this, googleSignInAccount);

    mPlayersClient.getCurrentPlayer()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Player>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Player> task) {
                    String displayName;


                    Log.i("playerId" , task.getResult().getPlayerId());
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        displayName = task.getResult().getDisplayName();
                        Uri uri = task.getResult().getIconImageUri();
                        Log.i("url", uri.toString());

                        CircleImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.testImage);
                        //ERROR : here when i use "this" it gets red underline
                        ImageManager manager = ImageManager.create(this);
                        manager.loadImage(imageView, uri, R.drawable.defualt_user_img);


                    }
```

The uri is of content scheme so I can't use Picasso. When I hover cursor over "this" it shows

> Create (android.content.Context) in ImageManager cannot be applied to
>   (anonymous
>   com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener)

Comment: It would help if you told us what error you were getting,

Comment: @ScottCooper , I get no error in logs as i can't run the code, because when when I do `ImageManager manager = ImageManager.create(this);` , "this" get  red underlined

Comment: @ScottCooper I updated the question with more info. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: @abielita when I run app it throws error -error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnCompleteListener<Player>> cannot be converted to Context
. I tried to declare imageManager as a member class and initialize it onCreate , doing so i was able to fill imageView with the placeholder image but still no luck in loading uri

Comment: You need to provide a context object. If this is running in an activity, you can do so by referencing the outer class with something like `ImageManager manager = ImageManager.create(OuterActivity.this);`

Comment: @Caleb_Allen Yes, I'm running this under an Activity and I already tried `ActivityName.this`, it doesn't throw any error nor it loads Uri or the placeholder Image. I also tried `getBaseContext()`, `getApplicationContext()` . and same thing happens. No error, No loading of the image. However when I declared imageManager as a member class and initialized it `onCreate` it was at least loading placeholder. So, I wonder if `ImageManager` is the right way to load content scheme uri or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use CircleImageView library i.e ,    `implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'` . Apparently it doesn't support *content scheme uri* or play games don't support it, not sure which one is the case but it will work fine if you use android ImageView.

Here is the final working code.

```
 ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.testImage);
 ImageManager manager = ImageManager.create(getApplicationContext());
 manager.loadImage(imageView,uri);
```